# adding app to home screen using adb

Tags: android, adb

I was wondering if there was a way to add an app link to the homescreen of a phone using adb or adb shell? Basically just need an automated way to do this after installing the apps to the phone.

Basically the same as long pressing an app and dragging it to the homescreen.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to launch applications? Please, clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me "add an app to the homescreen of a phone using adb or adb shell?"

Comment: I can assume following cases: 1. add link to the application to a homescreen 2. launch application 3. add appwidget of the application to the homescreen

Comment: Cleared it up a litte, however... i mention nothing about "launching an app".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to do this through ADB or ADB shell. So i just created an app to do this for me.

Comment: How about sharing the source of that app? That would be really helpful for those with a similar problem.